# Exporting all report SQLs from a Microstrategy project

Tags: export-to-excel, microstrategy

Is there a way to export the SQL of all the reports of a project in MicroStrategy?

Answer (score 0):

Get the SQL view of a previously created report instance, using the in-memory report instance created by a POST /reports/{reportId}/instances request. You obtain the authorization token needed to execute the request using POST /auth/login; you obtain the project ID using GET /projects. You pass the authorization token and the project ID in the request header. You specify the report ID and report instance ID in the path of the request.
Use below open API,
https://demo.microstrategy.com/MicroStrategyLibrary/api-docs/index.html#/Reports/getReportSqlView